# How to access data inside of a useEffect block from outside of it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, components

So basically, I have a DateView component from which I retrieve a date in a ChooseCalendar component. However I have the code that retrieves this data from DateView in a useEffect block because I'm passing a dateType variable which is part of a useState to the component. The issue with this is in the ChooseCalendar component I cant access the data in the props of the DateView component. The data I want to access being the value that onDateTypeChange stores. Is there a way of fixing this so I can access this data?

Here is my ChooseCalendar.js component :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import DateView from '../components/DateView';

export default function ChooseCalendar(props) {
  const [calendarType, setCalendarType] = useState('day');
  const [calendarView, setCalendarView] = useState(null);
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);

  // Retrieve dropdown value and pass it to props
  const handleCalendarTypeChange = (event) => {
    const newCalendarType = event.target.value;
    setCalendarType(newCalendarType);
    props.onCalendarTypeChange(newCalendarType);
  };

  const handleDateTypeChange = useCallback((date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let newCalendarView;
    if (calendarType === 'day') {
      newCalendarView = <DateView dateType="day" onDateTypeChange={handleDateTypeChange} />;
    } else if (calendarType === 'week') {
      newCalendarView = <DateView dateType="week" onDateTypeChange={handleDateTypeChange} />;
    } else if (calendarType === 'month') {
      newCalendarView = <DateView dateType="month" onDateTypeChange={handleDateTypeChange} />;
    }
    setCalendarView(newCalendarView);
  }, [calendarType, handleDateTypeChange]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedDate) {
      props.onDateTypeChange(selectedDate);
      console.log('Calendar selected date : ', selectedDate);
    }
  }, [selectedDate, props.onDateTypeChange]);

  return (
    <section className="border-4 rounded-lg p-2 px-28 bg-red-400 text-slate-800">
      <h2 className="text-xl font-bold">Calendar Settings</h2>
      <p className="font-semibold mb-1">Change your calendar settings</p>
      <select onChange={handleCalendarTypeChange} className="w-56 border-4 rounded p-2 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-slate-800">
        <option value="day">Day View</option>
        <option value="week">Week View</option>
        <option value="month">Month View</option>
      </select>
      {calendarView}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Here is my DateView.js component :

```
export default function dateViewDisplayer(props){
  const dateType = props.dateType;

  const handleDateTypeChange = (event) => {
    const date = event.target.value;
    props.onDateTypeChange(date);
  };

  if (dateType === 'day'){
    return (
      <section>
        <p className="font-semibold mb-1">Choose your day</p>
        <input onChange={handleDateTypeChange} className="w-56 border-4 rounded p-2 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-slate-800" type="date" />
      </section>
    );
  }

  if (dateType === 'week'){
    return (
      <section>
        <p className="font-semibold mb-1">Choose your week</p>
        <input onChange={handleDateTypeChange} className="w-56 border-4 rounded p-2 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-slate-800" type="week" />
      </section>
    );
  }

  if (dateType === 'month'){
    return (
      <section>
        <p className="font-semibold mb-1">Choose your month</p>
        <input onChange={handleDateTypeChange} className="w-56 border-4 rounded p-2 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-slate-800" type="month" />
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering if it may be easier to use conditional rendering rather than storing the new component in state. How about giving something like this a try? Notice that the `calenderView` state and `useEffect` is no longer needed, and you can now pass the desired `handleDateTypeChange` prop like normal.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import DateView from '../components/DateView';

export default function ChooseCalendar(props) {
  const [calendarType, setCalendarType] = useState('day');
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);

  // Retrieve dropdown value and pass it to props
  const handleCalendarTypeChange = (event) => {
    const newCalendarType = event.target.value;
    setCalendarType(newCalendarType);
    props.onCalendarTypeChange(newCalendarType);
  };

  const handleDateTypeChange = useCallback((date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedDate) {
      props.onDateTypeChange(selectedDate);
      console.log('Calendar selected date : ', selectedDate);
    }
  }, [selectedDate, props.onDateTypeChange]);

  return (
    <section className='border-4 rounded-lg p-2 px-28 bg-red-400 text-slate-800'>
      <h2 className='text-xl font-bold'>Calendar Settings</h2>
      <p className='font-semibold mb-1'>Change your calendar settings</p>
      <select
        onChange={handleCalendarTypeChange}
        className='w-56 border-4 rounded p-2 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-slate-800'
      >
        <option value='day'>Day View</option>
        <option value='week'>Week View</option>
        <option value='month'>Month View</option>
      </select>
      {calendarType === 'day' && (
        <DateView dateType='day' onDateTypeChange={handleDateTypeChange} />
      )}

      {calendarType === 'week' && (
        <DateView dateType='week' onDateTypeChange={handleDateTypeChange} />
      )}

      {calendarType === 'month' && (
        <DateView dateType='month' onDateTypeChange={handleDateTypeChange} />
      )}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Update:

Or even simpler, because it looks like `dateType` is the same as `calendarType`, could you just do this (shortened to highlight just the change in the return value):

```
...
export default function ChooseCalendar(props) {
  ...
  return (
    <section className='border-4 rounded-lg p-2 px-28 bg-red-400 text-slate-800'>
      <h2 className='text-xl font-bold'>Calendar Settings</h2>
      <p className='font-semibold mb-1'>Change your calendar settings</p>
      <select
        onChange={handleCalendarTypeChange}
        className='w-56 border-4 rounded p-2 bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-slate-800'
      >
        <option value='day'>Day View</option>
        <option value='week'>Week View</option>
        <option value='month'>Month View</option>
      </select>
        <DateView dateType={calendarType} onDateTypeChange={handleDateTypeChange} />
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: The second one worked for me. The reason why I had used the useEffect block was because useState is asynchronous so I wanted to wait for the value to have changed before updating. But i realize now that it updates live and is quick enough for there to barely be a difference. Thanks for the help.